# How to resolve dependency errors with Maven

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-enforcer-plugin

I am trying to resolve conflicts between libraries in my Maven project. I added the following plugin to the plugins section:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <rules><dependencyConvergence/></rules>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

When I run `mvn enforcer:enforce`, I get different dependency errors like this one:

```
Dependency convergence error for org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13 paths to dependency are:
+-org.test:service:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.2.0
    +-org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.2.0
      +-org.apache.avro:avro:1.7.7
        +-org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13
and
+-org.test:service:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.2.0
    +-org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.2.0
      +-org.apache.avro:avro-mapred:1.7.7
        +-org.apache.avro:avro-ipc:1.7.7
          +-org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13
and
+-org.test:service:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.2.0
    +-org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.2.0
      +-org.apache.avro:avro-mapred:1.7.7
        +-org.apache.avro:avro-ipc:1.7.7
          +-org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13
and
+-org.test:service:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.2.0
    +-org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.2.0
      +-org.apache.avro:avro-mapred:1.7.7
        +-org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13
and
+-org.test:service:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.2.0
    +-org.apache.parquet:parquet-hadoop:1.8.2
      +-org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.11
```

So, how can I resolve these errors when I package the JAR? In SBT it is easier, but I get stuck with Maven.

Answer (score 0):

This means that

```
org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl
```

is found in different versions in your `dependency:tree`. You need to choose which version you want to have. You usually do this by using `<dependencyManagement>` like

```
<dependencyManagement>
   ...
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.13</version>
   </dependency>
   ...
</dependencyManagement>
```